# HBO horror movie with a super-strong killer

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, androids

Okay, this is gonna be vague, but I'm hoping someone can put these pieces together and help me figure out a movie scene that has been in my head for years!

While at a friend's house in the 80's, we were watching HBO. While waiting for Swamp Thing to come on, there was another flick from what I recall is an android gone bad. However, I can't be sure it was an android and not simply a hyper-strong killer. Anyway, the scene I remember is a person standing in a doorway, when the killer grabs the victim over the mouth (as if to stop them from screaming), and slams the victim into the wall. The victim slides down the wall with a blood streak remaining.

We got a bit freaked out and turned it off prior to the ending, but I was told that the killer (possible android) ends up falling down a well.

Does any of that ring a bell?!

I apologize for the vagueness, but it's all I got and I thought folks here could help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The indestructible killer in the 1982 Chuck Norris film [Silent Rage](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084684/) fell down a well at the end of the film.  They thought he was dead, but in a twist ending that shocked nobody the final scene showed him emerging back out of the water.

Comment: I can't believe it! Silent Rage is it! Holy cow!

Answer (score 3):

The part where the killer ends up falling down a well sounds like the ending of Halloween 4. Michael Myers is the killer in these movies. As for the super strength, he has had some incredible feats of strength.

- He's been known to pick up victims with one arm and kill them with the other.
- He's squished peoples heads in with his bare hands.
- I believe in the movie you're referring to he bent a shotgun barrel with his hands.
- He's rammed a shotgun through someone, which then went through a wall behind them.

Comment: I am a horror fan, and I know its not a mainstream franchise like Halloween. I'm also thinking it is a lot earlier like early 80's due to remembering watching Swamp Thing.

Thank you for the input though! I know this is tough based on one vague scene!

Comment: @JohnR Yeah was thinking how did you not know, this clears it up. Basically matched the description, but not it. haha and swamp thing  was awesome.